# how to use jjqueryscrollto plugin?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use this pluggin. How can i use this ? the examples are not very clear on using it.

Can someone show me how  to use this pluggin correctly? pluggin [JqueryScrollto](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

I tried the examples as shownbelow :

```
<li><a title="$(...).scrollTo( 'li:eq(14)', 800 );" id="relative-selector" href="#">Relative selector</a></li>

<div id="pane-target" class="pane">
    <ul class="elements" style="height:1011px; width:1820px;">
        <li>
            <p>0</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>1</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>2</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>3</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>4</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>5</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>6</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>7</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>8</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>9</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>10</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>11</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>12</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>13</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>14</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>15</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>16</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>17</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>18</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>19</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>20</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>21</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>22</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>23</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>24</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>25</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>26</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>27</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>28</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>29</p><a href="#" title="$(...).scrollTo( 0, 800, {queue:true} );" class="back">go back</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("ul li a.back").click(function () {
    $.scrollTo(0, 800, {
        queue: true
    });

    return false;
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/88JxN/1/)